# Pandas groupby cumulative count

Tags: python, pandas

How do I do a cumcount on two groupings, id and name?  For example I have:

```
id  name
1   name1
1   name1
1   name2
2   name3
2   name3
2   name3
```

And I would like it to look like:

```
id  name   cumcount
1   name1  1 
1   name1  2
1   name2  1
2   name3  1
2   name3  2
2   name3  3
```

Basically a running tally for each name in an id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `groupby.cumcount`:

```
df['cumcount'] = df.groupby(['id', 'name']).cumcount() + 1

df
#  id   name    cumcount
#0  1   name1   1
#1  1   name1   2
#2  1   name2   1
#3  2   name3   1
#4  2   name3   2
#5  2   name3   3
```