# How to add sequential numbers to unique values in pandas dataframe column until condition met?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a daraframe with telephone numbers, call dates, account numbers, and IF APPLICABLE an order number and order value.

I want to tell how many calls it took to each telephone number before there WAS an order. I thought listing which call number it was would help. So sorted the by date but then I've hit a brick wall.

```
NUMBER       CALL DATE     ACC        ORDERNO       VALUE
07554655235  01/01/2019    XXX1       NAN           NAN
07554655235  01/01/2019    XXX1       NAN           NAN
07554655235  02/01/2019    XXX1       NAN           NAN
01926152623  02/01/2019    AAA1       ORD13345      65.32
07554655235  03/01/2019    XXX1       NAN           NAN
01125623333  04/01/2019    BBB1       NAN           NAN
07554655235  05/01/2019    XXX1       NAN           NAN
07554655235  05/01/2019    XXX1       NAN           NAN
07554655235  06/01/2019    XXX1       ORD13345      22.95
```

Other than writing a function to iterate through the rows (which i believe is bad practice). Is there a way I can list out which call number it is (**for that unique number and account number), and list numbers seqentially until there is an order found and then reset back to call 1.

Notes: There are multiple telphone numbers, multiple accounts etc, each which needs to have its only sequental numbering.

My desired output is below - notice orders for AAA1 and BBB1 have their own numbering

```
NUMBER       CALL DATE     ACC        ORDERNO       VALUE    CALL NO
07554655235  01/01/2019    XXX1       NAN           NAN      1
07554655235  01/01/2019    XXX1       NAN           NAN      2
07554655235  02/01/2019    XXX1       NAN           NAN      3
01926152623  02/01/2019    AAA1       ORD13345      65.32    1  
07554655235  03/01/2019    XXX1       NAN           NAN      4
01125623333  04/01/2019    BBB1       NAN           NAN      7
07554655235  05/01/2019    XXX1       NAN           NAN      5
07554655235  05/01/2019    XXX1       NAN           NAN      6
07554655235  06/01/2019    XXX1       ORD13345      22.95    7
07554655235  06/01/2019    XXX1       NAN           NAN      1
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `df.groupby('NUMBER').cumcount()+1`?

Comment: I think it is [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23435270)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas groupby cumulative count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44034627/pandas-groupby-cumulative-count)

Comment: no, becuase I want it to RESET back to ZERO once it finds a value in the "value" column.